# Python: Generating multiple lat/longs between two predetermined GPS points and saving to .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gps, export-to-csv

My goal is to take 2 known GPS points (lat/long) and generate the lat/long between those 2 points in a straight line.

I found some code that gets me 90% of the way there:

```
import math
import csv

def getPathLength(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2):
    '''calculates the distance between two lat, long coordinate pairs'''
    R = 6371000 # radius of earth in m
    lat1rads = math.radians(lat1)
    lat2rads = math.radians(lat2)
    deltaLat = math.radians((lat2-lat1))
    deltaLng = math.radians((lng2-lng1))
    a = math.sin(deltaLat/2) * math.sin(deltaLat/2) + math.cos(lat1rads) * math.cos(lat2rads) * math.sin(deltaLng/2) * math.sin(deltaLng/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = R * c
    return d

def getDestinationLatLong(lat,lng,azimuth,distance):
    '''returns the lat an long of destination point 
    given the start lat, long, aziuth, and distance'''
    R = 6378.1 #Radius of the Earth in km
    brng = math.radians(azimuth) #Bearing is degrees converted to radians.
    d = distance/1000 #Distance m converted to km
    lat1 = math.radians(lat) #Current dd lat point converted to radians
    lon1 = math.radians(lng) #Current dd long point converted to radians
    lat2 = math.asin(math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(d/R) + math.cos(lat1)* math.sin(d/R)* math.cos(brng))
    lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng) * math.sin(d/R)* math.cos(lat1), math.cos(d/R)- math.sin(lat1)* math.sin(lat2))
    #convert back to degrees
    lat2 = math.degrees(lat2)
    lon2 = math.degrees(lon2)
    return[lat2, lon2]

def calculateBearing(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2):
    '''calculates the azimuth in degrees from start point to end point'''
    startLat = math.radians(lat1)
    startLong = math.radians(lng1)
    endLat = math.radians(lat2)
    endLong = math.radians(lng2)
    dLong = endLong - startLong
    dPhi = math.log(math.tan(endLat/2.0+math.pi/4.0)/math.tan(startLat/2.0+math.pi/4.0))
    if abs(dLong) > math.pi:
         if dLong > 0.0:
             dLong = -(2.0 * math.pi - dLong)
         else:
             dLong = (2.0 * math.pi + dLong)
    bearing = (math.degrees(math.atan2(dLong, dPhi)) + 360.0) % 360.0;
    return bearing

def main(interval,azimuth,lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2):
    '''returns every coordinate pair inbetween two coordinate 
    pairs given the desired interval'''

    d = getPathLength(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
    remainder, dist = math.modf((d / interval))
    counter = float(interval)
    coords = []
    coords.append([lat1,lng1])
    for distance in range(0,int(dist)):
        coord = getDestinationLatLong(lat1,lng1,azimuth,counter)
        counter = counter + float(interval)
        coords.append(coord)
    coords.append([lat2,lng2])
    return coords

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #point interval in meters
    interval = 1.0
    #direction of line in degrees
    #start point
    lat1 = 58.294858
    lng1 = -148.200708
    #end point
    lat2 = 58.276672
    lng2 = -148.188580
    azimuth = calculateBearing(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
    print (azimuth)
    coords = main(interval,azimuth,lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
    print (coords)
    header = ['Lat','Long']
    data = [coords]
    with open('Y:/Gulf of Alaska IYS/IYS Data_Feb-Apr_2022/gps/Gretel_Coords_test.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)
            writer.writerow(data)
```

the headers on the csv file this generates is fine but the lat/long is printed on one row. What I'm trying to accomplish is for these generated GPS points to be recorded in a new row each time and for lat/long to be in 2 separate columns. Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coords` is already a list of x-y coordinate pairs, but then you put it into another list with the line `data = [coords]`, so then when you call `writer.writerow(data)`, it will just dump the entire list as a single row of data.

What you want is to call [`csv.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) (notice the plural, it's designed to write multiple rows instead of one) with `coords`, like in this version of your `__main__` block.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #point interval in meters
    interval = 1.0
    #direction of line in degrees
    #start point
    lat1 = 58.294858
    lng1 = -148.200708
    #end point
    lat2 = 58.276672
    lng2 = -148.188580
    azimuth = calculateBearing(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
    #print (azimuth)
    coords = main(interval,azimuth,lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
    #print (coords)
    header = ['Lat','Long']
    with open('Y:/Gulf of Alaska IYS/IYS Data_Feb-Apr_2022/gps/Gretel_Coords_test.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(coords)
```

And I get this in the resulting CSV file:

```
❯ head -n10 coords.csv
Lat,Long
58.294858,-148.200708
58.294849522637115,-148.20070234510936
58.294841045273984,-148.20069669022146
58.29483256791059,-148.20069103533626
58.294824090546946,-148.2006853804538
58.29481561318306,-148.200679725574
58.294807135818935,-148.20067407069692
58.29479865845454,-148.20066841582255
58.294790181089915,-148.20066276095088

# etc.
```